# How to use authentication info of facebook, google... in Yii

Tags: php, authentication, yii

My website uses a default Yii user model: user->id, user->username ...
Almost activation on website bases on user account.

Then, I included login via Google, facebook... by using [Eauth](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth) extention. This extension works well now. I could get user name, user id from them.

The problem is my website controls processes by using only Yii's user account, so Google's account can not do any thing.

How to sync Yii's user account with a Google or Facebook user account?

Comment: What exactly do mean by syncing? Do you want to get additional details?

Comment: Could you post your login code? so I can help?

Comment: I think I got the solution, fetch the email from social networks then login with that email if it has already existed in my web app, otherwise, I'll register new user base on authentiation info from social networks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy indeed.

First you have to create one table/model for your users (or use the one you already have).

Then, on the action that is called back from OAuth (mine is called `SiteController/actionLoginGoogleDo`) you have to hook into the standard Yii user management. I wrote these few lines of code and everything worked like magic (login/logout/`Yii::app()->user`/ecc):

```
public function actionLoginGoogleDo()
{
    // Replace the next line with your Eauth extension
    $email = Yii::app()->googlePlus->getDetails();

    // Here fetch your user model.
    // In my case if a user is not found, a new one is created.
    $user = User::getUser($email);

    // This is the actual hook in the Yii framework
    $identity=new UserIdentity($email, null);
    $duration; // days
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration);

    // Redirect to the main controller/action
    $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the line "$duration; // days"

Comment: Sure, sorry. It is the expiration time of the login. Here I had disabled it because I was still developing. You can figure out how to set it by looking at the file `protected/models/LoginForm`. There, it is defined as: `$duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days`